# Laravel 5 - Call to undefined method App\Role::firstOrCreate()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am getting an extremely bizarre error in Laravel 5.5 when I try to run my database seeds. When I run `php artisan db:seed --class=RoleSeeder`, I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method App\Role::firstOrCreate()

Here is my `RoleSeeder` class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {


        //Application User: All users have this role be default
        $r = \App\Role::firstOrCreate(['name'=>'app-user'],
            [
                'name'         => 'app-user',
                'display_name' => 'All users of the application',
                'description'  => 'Uses the application',
            ]
        );


    }
}
```

I've used this snippet code several times in many Laravel 5.4 projects without issue. I had this error occur on another Laravel 5.5 project which mysteriously resolved itself, but now I'm unable to figure out why this is occurring again on a fresh project.

When I run the above snippet of code in laravel tinker (an interactive php session), it works flawlessly as expected.

I have verified the `firstOrCreate` function exists in 
`vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php`.

My `Role` Class is directly copied from the [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) library documentation:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{
}
```

When I change the `Role` class to extend `Model` directly, `db:seed` command runs fine. However, the error occurs when `Role` extends `EntrustRole`, which is defined as follows:

```
class EntrustRole extends Model implements EntrustRoleInterface
{
//..
```

I'll implement a workaround for now, but if anyone can shed some light on why this works fine in `php artisan tinker`, but not when running as a seeder, that would be great.

**Edit:**
Upon further investigation, it appears to only occur very sporadically:

```
user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.
user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan db:seed
Seeding: RoleSeeder


  [BadMethodCallException]
  Call to undefined method App\Role::firstOrCreate()


user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.
user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.
user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.
user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan cache:clear
Cache cleared successfully.
user@localmachine:/var/www/MyProject$ sudo php artisan db:seed
Seeding: RoleSeeder
Seeding: UserSeeder
```

Answer (score 0):

After switching the cache driver to redis, the issue is now resolved. I now realize this is what probably "mysteriously" fixed my other Laravel 5.5 project as well (when I switched the cache driver to memcached). Seems like a bug with Laravel 5.5 and the file cache driver